# How to add a delay between function excutions

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I am creating this little chatbox thing with socket.io, and I am wondering how I can add a delay between message sending to prevent spam and such.

Here is my code for sending a message.

```js
    // Sends a chat message
    const sendMessage = () => {
        let message = $inputMessage.val();
        // Prevent markup from being injected into the message
        message = cleanInput(message);
        // if there is a non-empty message and a socket connection
        if (message && connected) {
            $inputMessage.val("");
            addChatMessage({ username, message });
            // tell server to execute 'new message' and send along one parameter
            socket.emit("new message", message);
        }
    };
```

Comment: You could add a variable that tracks the time of the most recently sent message and a comparison of this variable and the current time; if the difference is too small, refuse to send it.

Comment: Do you want to STOP a message that's sent too soon after a previous message, or do you want to DELAY a message that's sent too soon after a previous message? If you're sure you want to Delay it, you should consider writing a Queue class, where you can add records (or functions) onto the queue and process them one by one in a timed, controlled manner

Comment: Dang, this is my first question that has gotten a answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a variable that tracks the time of the most recently sent message and a comparison of this variable and the current time; if the difference is too small, refuse to send it.

Minimal example:

```
window.lastMessageTime = 0;
function sendMessage(message) {
  if(Date.now() - window.lastMessageTime < 5000)
    return false;
  window.lastMessageTime = Date.now();
  // Proceed
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using setTimeout to execute your main function. Javascript is not supporting any delays as it is single threaded.